# How to make a blog application that plugs into other rails applications?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to have a blog functionality for some of the applications I have, Instead of developing and maintaining them as part of each application, I would like to develop a blog application and plug it right into other applications and maintain a single code base.

What approach should I take to accomplish this? Or Is there a gem that already does this?

Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/radar/forem

Comment: http://pullmonkey.com/2009/02/11/blog-plugin-tutorial-for-ruby-on-rails/

Maybe that helps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Rails engine sounds like your best bet. An engine is an application that provides functionality to its host application. [Getting Started with Engines](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html) guide is a great place to start and just so happens to guide you through the process of creating a blog engine. There are such engines that exist in the wild, such as [Blogit](https://github.com/KatanaCode/blogit). Whatever you decide, running through the engine guide would give you a good understanding of how engines work.